# Is there a way, to make Drupal not insert any Comments- or CDATA Tags into my Source-Code?

Tags: drupal, cdata

I inserted the following code into a content-field in Drupal and choosed «Source-Code» as type of content.

```
<script src="https://someWebsite.ch/libraries/processing.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvasHolder" style="max-width: 600px;">
  <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="mycanvas">

  PShape[] q = new PShape[63];
  float[] qx = { -22.5, 22.5, 26.25, 50.625, 54.375, 78.75, 82.5, 127.5};
  [a lot more processing code]

</script>
```

This code has a script-tag at the beginning, which includes a javascript-library (processing.min.js), a div-tag with a canvas and another script-tag containing the processing-code itself.

Somehow Drupal inserts weird comments- and CDATA-tags between the opening processing-script-tag and the processing-code, with the effect, that browsers do not run the processing-code.

If I remove these comments- and Cdata-Tags with the chrome-developper-console clientsided, the website is running like expected.

Is there a way to force Drupal to exactly giving out, what I inserted in the content-field, without adding any character?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. I know nothing about Drupal, but I'm pretty sure others will need more info to be able to help you: what is the "source-code" you inserted, for instance? Please also format the text you added.

Comment: Hi Joël, I edited my post and hope it will clarify my problem and it fits the rules of stackoverflow.